# Squid blocks automatic updates - antivirus and java

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I have Squid3 configured as a transparent proxy on a linux server.
I am trying to allow automatic updates of windows (currently disabled), java and antivirus programs to pass through.
The automatic updates of malwarebytes, antivir and avast fail. I am not clear whether they succeed when I manually start the updates; they say they have succeeded, but I am not convinced.
When I update java, the downloads and updating happens smoothly until the very last step of installation. Then it fails due to a proxy issue.

Any thoughts would be very helpful. I have searched and worked on this for a very long time with no success.

Below is my squid.conf file:

```
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl work_hours time M T W H F A 8:00-16:00
acl SSL_ports port 443      
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl windowsupdate dstdomain windowsupdate.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain .update.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain download.windowsupdate.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain redir.metaservices.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain images.metaservices.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain c.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain www.download.windowsupdate.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain wustat.windows.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain crl.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain sls.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain productactivation.one.microsoft.com
acl windowsupdate dstdomain ntservicepack.microsoft.com
acl wuCONNECT dstdomain www.update.microsoft.com
acl wuCONNECT dstdomain sls.microsoft.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain adobe.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain java.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain sun.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain oracle.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain geotrust.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain symantec.com
acl javaupdate dstdomain javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain adobe.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain java.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain sun.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain oracle.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain geotrust.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain symantec.com
acl jvCONNECT dstdomain javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com
acl aviraupdate dstdomain personal.avira-update.net
acl aviraupdate dstdomain personal.avira-update.com
acl aviraupdate dstdomain professional.avira-update.net
acl aviraupdate dstdomain professional.avira-update.com
acl kasperskyupdate dstdomain geo.kaspersky.com
acl malwarebytesupdate dstdomain data-cdn.mbamupdates.com
acl malwarebytesupdate dstdomain mbam-cdn.malwarebytes.org
acl avastupdate dstdomain avast.com
acl avCONNECT dstdomain personal.avira-update.net
acl avCONNECT dstdomain personal.avira-update.com
acl avCONNECT dstdomain professional.avira-update.net
acl avCONNECT dstdomain professional.avira-update.com
acl kaspCONNECT dstdomain geo.kaspersky.com
acl mbamCONNECT dstdomain data-cdn.mbamupdates.com
acl mbamCONNECT dstdomain mbam-cdn.malwarebytes.org
acl avstCONNECT dstdomain avast.com
acl denied_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid3/denied_domains.acl"
acl time_denied_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid3/time_denied_domains.acl"
acl denied_files urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid3/denied_files.acl"
acl time_denied_files urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid3/time_denied_files.acl"
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny to_localhost
http_access deny denied_domains
http_access deny denied_files
http_access deny localnet work_hours time_denied_domains
http_access deny localnet work_hours time_denied_files
http_access deny CONNECT wuCONNECT localnet
http_access deny windowsupdate localnet
http_access allow CONNECT jvCONNECT localnet
http_access allow javaupdate localnet
http_access allow CONNECT avCONNECT localnet
http_access allow CONNECT kaspCONNECT localnet
http_access allow CONNECT mbamCONNECT localnet
http_access allow aviraupdate localnet
http_access allow kasperskyupdate localnet
http_access allow malwarebytesupdate localnet
http_access allow avastupdate localnet
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
reply_body_max_size 200 MB windowsupdate
reply_body_max_size 200 MB javaupdate
reply_body_max_size 200 MB aviraupdate
reply_body_max_size 200 MB kasperskyupdate
reply_body_max_size 200 MB malwarebytesupdate
reply_body_max_size 200 MB avastupdate
reply_body_max_size 20 MB localhost
reply_body_max_size 20 MB localnet
http_port 3128 intercept
maximum_object_size 200 MB
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 50000 16 256
cache_log /var/log/squid3/cache.log
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern -i microsoft.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i windowsupdate.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i windows.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i adobe.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i java.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i javadl.oracle.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i oracle.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i sun.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i sdlc-esd.sun.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i geotrust.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i symantec.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i (avgate|avira).*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|idx|gz|json|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i personal.avira-update.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|idx|gz|json|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i personal.avira-update.net/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|idx|gz|json|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i geo.kaspersky.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|idx|gz|zip) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i kaspersky.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|idx|gz|avc) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i data-cdn.mbamupdates.com/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|idx|gz|ref|conf) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i mbam-cdn.malwarebytes.org/.*\.(cab|exe|ms[i|u|f]|[ap]sf|wm[v|a]|dat|zip|idx|gz|ref|conf) 14400 80% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern ([^.]+.|)avast.com/.*\.(vpu|vpaa) 4320 100% 43200 reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i \.(3gp|7z|ace|asx|avi|bin|cab|dat|deb|divx|dvr-ms) 14400 80% 14400 ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i \.(rar|jar|gz|tgz|bz2|iso|m1v|m2(v|p)|mo(d|v)) 14400 80% 14400 ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i \.(jp(e?g|e|2)|gif|pn[pg]|bm?|tiff?|ico|swf|css|js|jpg|png) 14400 80% 14400 ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i \.(mp(e?g|a|e|1|2|3|4)|mk(a|v)|ms(i|u|p)|og(x|v|a|g)|rar|rm|r(a|p)m|snd|vob|wav) 14400 80% 14400 ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern -i \.(pp(s|t)|wax|wm(a|v)|wmx|wpl|zip|cb(r|z|t)) 14400 80% 14400 ignore-private override-expire override-lastmod reload-into-ims
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
range_offset_limit 200 MB windowsupdate
range_offset_limit 200 MB aviraupdate
range_offset_limit 200 MB javaupdate
range_offset_limit 200 MB kasperskyupdate
range_offset_limit 200 MB malwarebytesupdate
range_offset_limit 200 MB avastupdate
request_body_max_size 20 MB
icp_port 3130
always_direct allow all
```

Thanks very much. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look to Squid logs to see what is blocking?

Comment: Hi. Yes I have looked at all the logs but without much success (this is more due to lack of knowledge of what to look for). We have 100 users so the logs fill up quickly and it is hard to separate information. That being said, I have tried to update Java and mbam, and very little shows up. Is there anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: On the squid logs you should see what is requested and if it is allowed or denied. Furthermore as you configured as transparent proxy, as far as I remember this would only work for HTTP and not for HTTPS, if you want to proxy HTTPS then you should configure the browsers/OS.

Comment: Hi again. I finally got things working. The domain names needed a '.' before them: .sun.com instead of sun.com . It now seems to work. I also adjusted some proxy settings on the antivirus programs to bypass a proxy rather than use system proxy. Now it all works well! Thanks the help.